# Наложение картинки на видео C#

Tags: c#, видео

Сейчас я использую FFmeg для наложения картинки для видео, для одного потока это работает хорошо, но в многопоточном режиме FFmeg перестает работать, я попробовал копировать папку FFmeg в новую директорию перед запуском, но это не помогло.

```
count++;
Copy(@"C:\\Video\FFMpeg", $"C:\\\\Video\\FFMpeg{count}");
string FFmegPath = $"C:\\\\Video\\FFMpeg{count}";
string videoPath = Path.GetFileName(item);
Console.WriteLine($"Обработка видео: {videoPath} начата");
string videoPathExtension = Path.GetExtension(videoPath);
string videoPathResult = videoPath.Replace(Path.GetExtension(videoPathExtension), "");
videoPathResult = videoPathResult + "out" + videoPathExtension;
var compiler = $"{FFmegPath}\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i {videoPath} -i gr.png -filter_complex \"[1:v]format = argb,geq = r = \'r(X,Y)\':a = \'0.5*alpha(X,Y)\'[zork]; [0:v][zork] overlay \" -vcodec libx264 {videoPathResult} -y";
string cmd = compiler;
    
var proc = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    WorkingDirectory = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\Video",
    FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/c " + cmd,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
};
    
Process.Start(proc).WaitForExit(999999999);
Console.WriteLine($"Обработка видео: {videoPath} завершена");
File.Delete(item);
File.Move($"Video\\{videoPathResult}", item);
```

Подскажите как наложить картинку в многопоточном режиме, если не FFmeg использовать, то как лучше кодом этом сделать или какую библиотеку использовать.

Comment: Я не вижу здесь ни одного запуска потока, я вижу старт процесса, оч чем именно вопрос? И вам бы научиться `Path.Combine` и буквальные строки использовать. Что именно вы хотите делать параллельно? Конкретизируйте вопрос. Этот код работает или нет? Если не работает, то как именно вы это поняли?

Comment: Для начала: `WaitForExit(999999999)` - можно просто `WaitForExit()`. И если вы хотите использовать `WaitForExit()`, то `UseShellExecute` должен быть `false`.

Comment: @aepot проблема была в другом
var compiler = $"{FFmegPath}\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i {videoPath} -i gr.png -filter_complex \"[1:v]format = argb,geq = r = \'r(X,Y)\':a = \'0.5*alpha(X,Y)\'[zork]; [0:v][zork] overlay \" -vcodec libx264 {videoPathResult} -y";
{videoPath} так как cmd не принимает пути с пробелами или с кирилицей